# Декодировать поток byte[] формата jBig2

Tags: c#, pdf, jpeg, itextsharp, tif

Подскажите бесплатные библиотеки, для декодирования полученных из Pdf изображений. Использую iTextSharp. Но если, вытаскиваемое изображение формата jBig2 вылетает ошибка, что невозможно из данного массива байт получить изображение. Нашла данное решение https://github.com/devteamexpress/JBig2Decoder.NET/blob/master/JBig2Decoder/JBIG2StreamDecoder.cs но оно работает слишком медленно, (7 минут для pdf на 71 страницу). Есть ли еще бесплатные декодеры этого формата?